# drag behavior similar to loop dragging in iOS garage band

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uipopovercontroller, gestures

What's the best way to drag something out of a UIPopoverController, similar to how loops get dragged from the loop browser (I'm assuming it's a UIPopoverController) in Garageband on iOS? Meaning, the popover gets dismissed as soon as the user drags outside of it.

I tried implementing it via gestures, but as soon as I dismiss the popover, the gestures and therefore the dragging gets invalidated.

Is there a way to hide the popover, so I can dismiss it at the end of the drag? Or are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: could you provide your code?